# Set first day of week on Trello calendar to Monday?

Tags: trello, calendar

Is it possible to set the first day of the week to Monday instead of Sunday for the due calendar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not currently possible. There is more work to be done with date formatting, timezones, etc.

Comment: Anyone know if this on the roadmap for development?

Comment: Any news on this? For me it is a really irritating, I always set wrong date becase the calendar is "wrong" :(

Comment: See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/48745/253119).

Answer (score 10):

It's now possible to choose Monday or Sunday, reportedly:  http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/1277216-setting-the-first-day-of-the-week-for-the-calendar

As a Canadian, I'm not big on switching to US spellings just to get Sunday at the start of the week, but at least it's possible now.

Comment: Confirmed! As a Belgian, **en-GB** is close enough for me.

Comment: The instructions on Trello's site are out of date: the language setting is now hidden in one's [Atlassian account _account preferences_](https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/account-preferences).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.