# Why is the calendar displayed sometimes with weeks starting on Sunday, and others Monday?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

When setting a 'Due Date' on a card, the calendar widget sometimes renders the month with weeks starting on Sundays, and at other times with weeks starting on Mondays. Is there a setting that controls this, or should I report a bug?

Comment: I can't seem to find a setting for this, neither in personal settings, board settings or organisation settings.

Answer (score 1):

It's now possible to choose Monday or Sunday, reportedly: http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/1277216-setting-the-first-day-of-the-week-for-the-calendar

*Browser locale* is the language you've set your browser (Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer...) although in my case it doesn't seem to work in any of the views for English UK (using Chrome).

Source: [Set first day of week on Trello calendar to Monday?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23786/set-first-day-of-week-on-trello-calendar-to-monday)